# How to get the URLs being cached in Django with its parameters?

Tags: django, caching

Is there a way to get the cached URLs with its parameters in Django?

I'm caching all the anonymous requests through the setting CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ANONYMOUS_ONLY = True`.`

My problem is that I would like to be able to delete particular keys if the content of a page changes (based on css, js changing or change in data from db). JFYI, I'm using memcached.

If this is not possible, how can I achieve the same goal?

Comment: An alternative to searching for a set of keys and forcefully removing them would just be setting an appropriate cache timeout. A 5 to 10 minute timeout should be appropriate, from the top of my head, without knowing your application. Obviously, a bit of measurement could help find a better time out.